# In LyX: Skipping numbers in enumerate and changing symbol of enumeration

Tags: lists, lyx, enumerate

I would like to skip numbers in a list. Consider the following example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item text1
\item[3.] text2
\item[22.] text3
\end{enumerate}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this **in LyX** (although it is obvious how to code it in the source code). I tried exporting, then changing and reimporting the document, however LyX doesn't properly read these changes.

A related questions is how to get the symbols in numbering to change in LyX, e.g. from 1., 2., 3., .... to i., ii., iii., ... , as shown below.

```
\begin{enumerate}[i]
\item text1
\item text2
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Numbering#enumListStartingNumber

Answer (score 7):

They are two quite different questions, but anyways.

### Custom labels on items

There are at least two possibilities:

1. At the beginning of the item, add the optional argument, e.g. `[22.]` within an ERT.
2. Use the ``Labeling'' list type instead of Enumerate. This is a LyX-specific list that uses the first word you type as the label of the item. Of course, this means that you have to specify the number on *all* the items manually.

### Arabic to roman

Go to Document --> Settings --> Modules, and add the *Customisable lists (enumitem)* module to your document. When you create a list, right click the *first* item, and choose **Insert Short Title**. Within the short title box, add an ERT, and type `label=\roman*.`. See the [`enumitem` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) for more details about what you can put here.

Comment: Thanks that worked.The second problem can also be solved (arabic to roman numbering) can also be solved using ERT!